# MySQL view taking forever

Tags: mysql, view, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

MySQL server 5.6

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6GB
key_buffer_size = 20M
```

Here is my schema:

```
TBL_1    TBL_2    TBL_3    TBL_4    TBL_5    TBL_6
id       id       id       id       id       id      (int, primary key, auto increment)
uid      uid      uid      uid      uid      uid     (varchar 100, key index)
dev      dev      dev      dev      dev      dev     (varchar 80)
intf     intf     intf     intf     intf     intf    (varchar 100)
stat1    stat2    stat3    stat4    stat5    stat6   (float, 11)
```

The uid field provides the unique relationship across the table rows.
count(*) across all tables is ~52K

My desired view:

```
VIEW_1
dev   intf   stat1   stat2   stat3   stat4   stat5   stat6
```

Here is an example of the view select sql I've tried thus far:

```
select a.dev, a.intf, a.stat1, b.stat2, c.stat3, d.stat4, e.stat_5, f.stat_6
from TBL_1 a
inner join TBL_2 b on b.uid = a.uid
inner join TBL_3 c on c.uid = a.uid
inner join TBL_4 d on d.uid = a.uid
inner join TBL_5 e on e.uid = a.uid
inner join TBL_6 f on f.uid = a.uid
```

Once I get beyond 2 joins the query becomes unresponsive.  For the above query explain return

```
|| *id* || *select_type* || *table* || *type* || *possible_keys* || *key* || *key_len* ||    *ref* || *rows* || *Extra*               ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || e       || ALL    || uid             ||       ||           ||          || 51391  ||                       ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || c       || ref    || uid             || uid   || 102       || db.e.uid || 1      || Using index condition ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || a       || ref    || uid             || uid   || 102       || db.c.uid || 1      ||                       ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || b       || ref    || uid             || uid   || 257       || db.c.uid || 1      || Using index condition ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || f       || ref    || uid             || uid   || 257       || db.c.uid || 1      || Using index condition ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || d       || ref    || uid             || uid   || 102       || db.e.uid || 1      || Using index condition ||
```

Any suggestions on how this could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Check explain plan for the query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * from ABC;
```

Check this [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

As per output of explain consider adding `indexes` or using other [Optimizing techniques](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html)

If this does not help paste your explain plan to look further.

Cheers !!

Comment: Perhaps you missed it but I included the optimizer execution plan at the bottom.  Cheers and thanks for your interest!